# soap messages over a single HTTP(S) connection

Tags: http, soap, connection

Can anyone give me an answer for the following question: 
I have a remote web service and a requirement about 100 TPS. (transaction per second ). As far as I know creation of the connection ( HTTP connection ) is quite expensive operation. So, I need to create just one HTTP connection with the web service and being able to send a lot of SOAP messages (envelopes) through that connection, so it be not one SOAP message and one HTTP connection, but many SOAP messages and one HTTP connection. Of course I need to create as much HTTP connections as I need, but each of them must serve to some SOAP messages.

May be there is some development pattern or other issue which I do not know.

I would very appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

SOAP does not have to be over HTTP. It just happens that it is nearly always implemented over HTTP.

If you really want to use SOAP you can use a socket, or message queue as well as HTTP. For an example see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51f6ye7k.aspx

However, I think if you need 100 TPS, SOAP is probably not the right technology to use.

Comment: @Dan: wouldn't WCF be a better choice?

Comment: @John if you're windows-based, certainly seems so.

Comment: @Dan: just curious: doesn't the link you posted require Windows?

Comment: Yes. I linked to it as one example of how you don't need HTTP for SOAP, which is true with or without Windows. That was just a windows-based example (we don't know what platform the OP is on.)

Comment: That is the point, that I certainly have to use SOAP over HTTP connection. And frankly speaking I am not the one who made this requirement - use SOAP and provide 100 tps. Thank you very much for you answer and for your advise, but I would like to know is it possible to organize sending multiple SOAP messages through one ( single ) HTTP connection, and if it is, can you provide some example on how to do this or provide some link. I've searched through the web on my question, but I still didn't manage to find the answer.

Thank you very much, for your participation!

Comment: P.S.: Is there some other way to rich 100tps requirement with sending SOAP messages to provided EndPoint ?